# What should be in the executable file name in the info.plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, submit

I am trying to submit an app to the appstore and I keep receiving this error:

```
This bundle is invalid, the executable name, as reported by CFBundleExecutable in the info.plist file, may not contain any of these charachters: / [] {} parenthesis . + *
```

The app executable name is as it has been since I first created the project:

```
${EXECUTABLE_NAME}
```

And the bundle ID, which is the same for the provisioning profile is like this:

```
com.ej.hw.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
```

That makes me think, should I change my exec file to my bundle ID, should I put some random thing or should I only take out the parts after the *$*?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your target name contains one of the forbidden characters.

See the image:

[image]

Change the Target Name. This is your problem, I'm sure you have a (/ [] {} parenthesis . + *) there.

Comment: I know it's been a while since this was asked and answered, but this answer has just helped us though 2 days of frustration! Thank you Gabriel, this answer was exactly what we needed.